# workflows and app permissions

Tags: 2013, workflow

Ive created a sp2013 workflow that queries ups and sets some permissions in various sites in various site collections.  Ive set the app permissions of the workflow to have full control with a tenant scope and created a few app steps in my workflow. Does setting the workflow to have full control over the tenancy mean that any workflows created in sites with the "Workflows can use App Permissions" enabled automatically inherit this right?